# PHP Object new method for Class, Memory Leak and Unset Method

Tags: php, class, object, memory-leaks, unset

I have Created following class in flie `index.class.php` :-

```
<?php
class index{
        public function loadTitle() {
            $title = "Welcome to My Website";
            return $title;
        }
    }
?>
```

and now, I am using it like below in my `index.php` file

```
    <?php
        require_once("index.class.php");
        $obj = new index();
        echo $obj->loadTitle();
    ?>
```

, now my question is Page will become heavy with lots of article and images, and i will expect 1500-2500 user every day in it.

Do, i need to also unset memory, i know PHP has its own garbage collector, but following URL scares me out :- [www.google.com/search?q=php+memory+leak+with+new](http://www.google.com/search?q=php%20memory%20leak%20with%20new)

and i saw few question in stackoverflow that it does consumes memory, and certain people have suggested to use `unset` function, but i am not sure, how to do it..

This is my try.. :-

Do i need to only call

```
<?php
    unset($obj); // At the end of the page, or where i will no more be using this object.
?>
```

or i have to set NULL value too.

```
<?php
    $obj = NULL;
    unset($obj);
?>
```

is above code fine for releasing memory, or do i need to do something else too.. Please suggest and teach me. It will be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Is this Question not worth Answering ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle Memory leak in PHP generated by "new" method of class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18575503/how-to-handle-memory-leak-in-php-generated-by-new-method-of-class)