# How to handle Memory leak in PHP generated by "new" method of class

Tags: php, class, memory

I have Created following class in flie `index.class.php` :-

```
<?php
class index{
        public function loadTitle() {
            $title = "Welcome to My Website";
            return $title;
        }
    }
?>
```

And now, I am using it like below in my `index.php` file

```
    <?php
        require_once("index.class.php");
        $obj = new index();
        echo $obj->loadTitle();
    ?>
```

My question because the Page will become heavy with lots of article and images, and I will expect 1500-2500 user every day in it.

Do I need to also unset memory, I know PHP has its own garbage collector, but following URL scares me out :- [www.google.com/search?q=php+memory+leak+with+new](http://www.google.com/search?q=php%20memory%20leak%20with%20new)

and I saw a few questions in StackOverflow saying it does consumes memory, and certain people have suggested to use the `unset` function, but I am not sure how to do it..

This is my attempt:

Do I need to only call

```
<?php
    unset($obj); // At the end of the page, or where i will no more be using this object.
?>
```

Or I have to set NULL value too.

```
<?php
    $obj = NULL;
    unset($obj);
?>
```

Is the above code fine for releasing memory, or do I need to do something else too? Please suggest and teach me!

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Object new method for Class, Memory Leak and Unset Method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558805/php-object-new-method-for-class-memory-leak-and-unset-method)

Comment: `new` doesn't leak memory, poor programmers leak memory. You don't need to `unset` variables at the end of the page, they'll be discarded when the request ends anyway. But you *do* need to pay attention to the amount of data you're loading into memory *during* page processing (e.g. data loaded from DB). Although all this is moot until you actually see that there are problems with the site load time.

Comment: If to much memory used is the problem. The solution is not 'fixing new memory leak'. The solution is writing better code that doesn't load to much data/bloatware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need to unset your variables all the time. I've seen people unset ALL their variables at the end of their PhP script, which is useless.

The only time where you'd want to unset variables is if you've memory problems in PhP and you can destroy variables you won't use anywhere else in your script, but you still have a lot of things to do (considering time or memory).

You might also want to give a look at :

http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/584960/whats-better-at-freeing-memory-with-php-unset-or-var-null

Comment: So, is there no real way to release memory used by assigned `object` or `variable` immediately on fly ? that's bad :(

Comment: I don't get what you mean in fact. You sure can release memory used by a variable, but it means you lose the content of the variable. Not sure I got what you're looking for, maybe should you check the link in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

PHP has automatic garbage collection. Every time you reassign `$obj`, if the old value is no longer accessible, its memory will be reclaimed. So you'll only ever have a reference to one object, not all the ones you ever created, unless you store them somewhere.

Comment: But how would php know, when `$obj` is no more required. ? I heard setting `$obj=NULL;` sets value to NULL and using `unset($obj)` makes it ready got garbage collection. Isn't this true ?

Comment: It doesn't know that. But it knows that the _previous_ value of `$obj` is no longer required, because there's no variable referencing it any more.

Comment: @johnsmith do you really want the answer to that question? If so, first learn about how garbage collection works. Then look up in the documentation what pattern apache mod_php uses for its garbage collection. click here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29

Answer (score 2):

You should look into the garbage collector of PHP. If you want, you can even force PHP to collect the garbage:

```
<?php
gc_enable(); // Enable Garbage Collector
var_dump(gc_enabled()); // true
var_dump(gc_collect_cycles()); // # of elements cleaned up
gc_disable(); // Disable Garbage Collector
?>
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php

Comment: This is what i am talking about, like java gives force garbage collection option.. I am interested to know the demerit or `don't` of above mentioned function, if there is any..

Comment: @johnsmith: Unless you have experience writing your own garbage collection mechanism from scratch, you'll just make things worse. What makes you think that PHP's memory manager is so incompetent that it will not cope with your 2000 requests per day? Don't touch the language guts until you have proof that there actually is a problem.

Comment: @DCoder It all depends on the server and the number of work required for each user.

Comment: Yes, but *when* the speed problem shows up, there are still loads of more effective things to do (use a profiler to find bottlenecks, reduce the number of DB queries, use external caching mechanisms...) before you have to get down to the garbage collector.

Comment: That is true. I just wanted to make it clear that PHP has an easily accessible garbage collector and that you shouldn't worry too much about memory leaks since PHP will take care of most of them automagically.

Comment: @DCoder and what makes you think i am not running memcache or have hardly 3 queries 1 page at time...

Comment: @johnsmith: if you are running memcache and still having a problem, you should mention that in the question. Or at least you should mention that the sample code you provided is not what you are actually running, although then I don't know *why* you posted it. Vague questions produce vague or incorrect answers.

Comment: my main concern was how memory allocated to php object are removed, as i would have created **same object variable ** in multiple instances, and before doing that, i found there is bug via search. now, i needed to release memory forcefully before proceeding to my stupidity.

Comment: Thanks. `gc_collect_cycles()` fix memory leaks caused by `new Class()`.